# How do I undo the command $ eval "$(docker-machine env blog)"

Tags: bash, docker, docker-machine

I think that command redirected `$ docker` commands to the docker machine.  Now all my docker commands are giving me an error `FATA[0000] Couldn't read ca cert...` follwed by the path to the docker-machine I created.  How can I fix my shell?

Answer (score 54):

What you are looking for is:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env -u)"
```

It will unset the `DOCKER_*` variables.

For the record, here's the output of `docker-machine env -u`:

```
unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
unset DOCKER_HOST
unset DOCKER_CERT_PATH
unset DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME
```

Comment: I am getting the message _Host "default" does not exist_.

Comment: Yes however above does not leave environment in condition prior to running docker-machine ... values prior to docker-machine are not saved for later ... it simply does an unset of docker-machine settings without restoring env settings to original settings ... we need to run a save-current-docker-settings before running docker-machine which post docker-machine and be used to restore original docker settings

Comment: Worked for me. I had switched to minikube docker context. I was able to go back to my 'regular' context by executing the 4 unset commands above. I am using Docker for mac community edition 18.06.1 on mac os High Sierra.

Comment: Running this command gives a `command not found`, instead it refers to use `eval $(docker-machine env -u)` - so without the quotes. Perhaps things have changed over the years?

Comment: When I try this on Windows, running `docker-machine env -u` is giving `'docker-machine' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

Answer (score 9):

You could also restart your shell. This will drop the variables that `minkube docker-env` exports.

Comment: This was a simple and easy fix for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that this is an old post but if someone else runs into this issue, who is new to docker like me this can help. By typing:

```
eval $(docker-machine env nameOfVm)
```

you are setting your current shell to use docker in that docker-machine. You can check if you type `docker-machine ls` 
that under active tab, that status is changed from `- to *` for that machine. You can also check which machine is active by running `docker-machine active`.

If you want to undo eval, just run:

```
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
```

and it will unset variables for active machine (You don't have to specify the name of the machine). This is all under macOS but I think it should be same on linux as well.
You can read more about this here:
[Docker documentation: docker-machine env](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/)

Answer (score 1):

I had been searching for an answer to this for quite awhile.  Shortly after posting the question on stackoverflow I realized typing in to the terminal the export commands docker gives on startup resolved my issue.

```
To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp:// some IP address
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH= some file path
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is **run**

```
docker-machine env machine-name
```

Then, copy and run the last segment in the output to set or remove the env variables.

Which looks like this in Windows :

```
eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env machine-name)
```

If it's set already, docker adds a "-u" at the tail to make the task easy.

like this in Windows :

```
eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env -u)
```

That's all.

Comment: This does not seem to add anything to the existing answers.