# Why does docker ps not show my minikube's docker containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am running minikube using the instructions at

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/

I started minikube:

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit
```

and verified that it is successfully running.

I am running 'Docker Community Edition' version 18.06.1-ce-mac73.

```
$ minikube ssh
```

is working fine.

However when I do

```
$ docker ps
```

on my mac os host, it doesn't show any containers. However, when I do

```
$ docker ps
```

after doing minikube ssh, I see about 20 containers.

So, where are the docker containers really running? Why does docker ps not show any containers on my mac?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following command to configure your Docker Host address:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Then, when you run `docker ps`, you should see your containers. Read more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/).

Comment: This is the correct solution. It does not matter where the containers are run, only which Docker socket you connect to.

Comment: How to revert the configuration ??

Answer (score 6):

Docker containers are not running on your MAC host.

They are running on a VM where you can do `minikube ssh` to that VM.

The docker ps shows the containers in there inside that VM.

Answer (score 2):

That's expected because you are using `hyperkit` driver to work as a hypervisor & launch lightweight virtual machines. Think of it as virtualbox launching VMs for you & complete k8s cluster is deployed into those VMs, all of them are well integrated.

Use below to get your virtual machine address or the server where these containers are actually running -

`$ minikube ip`

Ref - 
https://github.com/moby/hyperkit

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add a comment:

To revert the change in your shell, use

```
eval $(minikube docker-env -u)
```

as answered here: [How do I undo the command $ eval "$(docker-machine env blog)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550742/how-do-i-undo-the-command-eval-docker-machine-env-blog)